# $\epsilon>0$ there is a polynomial $p$ such that $|f(x)-e^{-x}p|<\epsilon\forall x\in[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, approximation-theory

Could any one tell me how to solve this one?

Given $f\in C[0,\infty)$ such that $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$ we need to show that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a polynomial $p$ such that $|f(x)-e^{-x}p(x)|<\epsilon \qquad \forall~ x\in[0,\infty)$

I just know the statement of Weierstrass Polynomial Approximation Theorem and that seems very far from the given problem, but somehow I feel I need to apply the theorem.

Comment: There is one rather complicated solution [here](http://statmathbc.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/solution-set-i/).

Comment: :-o :-o :-o so big solution :-o

Comment: @milind I upvoted your comment, but I don't agree with the term complicated. The idea is that we can define $f(+\infty):=0$ and we transform continuously $[0,+\infty]$ into $[0,1]$ in order to get a compact interval. Then we approximate. A further approximation (which needs technical verifications) gives what we want. So the given solution is actually conceptually simple, and I would be surprised if a simpler solution would exist.

Comment: @Davide Giraudo Hmm, thank you for the explanation. I confess that I did not understand the basic motivation behind the solution. Does the term "compact" here have a technical meaning?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo, superb explanation, Such a big proof needs this type of explanations. thanks ..

Comment: @MilindHegde "Does the term "compact" here have a technical meaning?"... Sure it has.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a "solution" (proof?) but I would like to give some details to your question.

$$
\vert f(x)-e^{-x}p(x)\vert=e^{-x}\vert g(x)-p(x)\vert,
$$
where $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-x}g(x)=0$. Your question is about the density of polynomials in the weighted space (weight function is $e^{-x}$) on the half-line. 
More info can be found [Stone-Weierstrass theorem (locally compact version)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone-Weierstrass_theorem#Locally_compact_version).
The literature of weighted approximation in $L_p$ spaces is huge.

Comment: appreciate your answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

We may consider $f$ defined on the compact space $[0, \infty]$, continuous, $f(\infty) =0$.

Consider the function $\phi(x) = \exp(-x)$. It separates the points and its only $0$ point is $\infty$. From Stone-Weierstrass theorem we conclude that the uniform closure $\mathbb{R}$- algebra of functions $\sum_{k\ge 1} a_k e^{-k x}$ is the algebra of continuous functions on $[0, \infty]$ that are $0$ at $\infty$.

Now, we want to approximate every $e^{-(k+1) x}$ ($k\ge 0$) by some $e^{-x}P(x)$, with $P(x)$ a polynomial.

Let's try first to approximate $e^{-2x}$. To do this we approximate $e^{-x}$ with its Taylor series and multiply. Note that we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2m} (-1)^k \frac{x^k}{k!} > e^{-x} > \sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} (-1)^k \frac{x^k}{k!}$$ for $x>0$
for any $m$, $n$ natural numbers. We conclude that
$$|e^{-x} - T_{n-1}(x)| < \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
where $T_{n-1}$ is the Taylor polynomial of order $n-1$ for $e^{-x}$. From here we get
$$|e^{-2x} - T_{n-1} e^{-x}| < e^{-x} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Now it is left to show that $\max_{x\ge 0} e^{-x} \frac{x^n}{n!} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. It is easy to see that for each $n$ the corresponding $\max$ is at $x=n$, so we need to see that
$$\frac{\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n}{n!}\to 0$$
as $n\to \infty$. Now Stirling formula is your friend.

One would be tempted to do similarly for $e^{-3x}$, $e^{-4x}$ and be done with it. However, the Taylor approximation estimate breaks down rather badly: the corresponding maximum will diverge as $n\to \infty$.

Another approach: try to show that the closure of $(e^{-x} P(x))_P$ is closed under multiplication. That would do it. So it's enough to show that $e^{-x} P(x) e^{-x} Q(x)$ can be approximated as $e^{-x} R(x)$. So it would be enough to show that $e^{-2x} x^l$ can be approximated for all $l\ge 0$. Again, Taylor expansion does not seem to work.

In the end, we recall the [Laguerre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials), and the fact that the associated functions form an orthogonal basis in $L^2[0, \infty)$. So now at least we know how to get for a nice function an approximating $e^{-x} P(x)$. This actually seems to be working very well. An  equivalent approach is to consider [Hermite polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials)  on $\mathbb{R}$.  The advantage is that the formulas seem to be neater. We can get ( at least formally)  the expansion of $e^{-x^2/(1-\rho^2)}$ in terms of $H_{2n}(x) e^{-x^2}$ by using the [Mehler formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehler_kernel)
$$\frac{\exp( - \frac{x^2 - 2 \rho x y + y^2}{1-\rho^2})}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}} = \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{(u/2)^n}{n!} H_n(x) e^{-x^2} H_n(y) e^{-y^2}$$

( [see](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=TaylorSeries%5B%20Exp%5Bx%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%5D%20Exp%5B%20-%20%28x%5E2%20-%202%20u%20x%20y%20%2B%20y%5E2%29%2F%281-u%5E2%29%5D%2F%20Sqrt%5B%281-u%5E2%29%5D%2C%20%7Bu%2C%200%2C%205%7D%5D) a WA testing).  Plug in the above $y=0$ and we get a series expansion
$$e^{-x^2/(1-\rho^2)} = \sqrt{1-\rho^2} \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{(\rho/2)^n}{n!}H_n(0) H_n(x) e^{-x^2}$$

([see](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=TaylorSeries%5BExp%5B%20-%20x%5E2%2F%281-u%5E2%29%5D%20Exp%5Bx%5E2%5D%2FSqrt%5B1-u%5E2%5D%2C%20%7Bu%2C%200%2C%2010%7D%5D) with WA). Note that $H_n(0) = 0$ for $n$ odd and $H_{2n}(x)$ is an even polynomial. Also, these are the physicists' polynomials.

We can wave our hands and claim that we have uniform convergence over $\mathbb{R}$ in the above expansion. This is probably so, but I don't have a source for that. More details are needed.

$\bf{Added:}$ It turns out that we can use Laguerre polynomials and the arguments are simpler. Consider the expansion

$$\frac{\exp(-\frac{x t}{1-t})}{1-t} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} L_n(x) t^n$$
where we can consider this just a formal expansion in $t$. Multiplying on both sides by $\exp(-x/2)$ we get
$$\exp(-\frac{1+t}{2(1-t)} x ) = (1-t)\sum_{n\ge 0} t^n L_n(x) e^{-x/2} $$

We look at it now as an expansion of a function of $x$, with $t$ a parameter. We can rewrite it as

$$e^{-a x} = \frac{2}{2a+1}\sum_{n\ge 0} (\frac{2a-1}{2a+1})^n L_n(x) e^{-x/2}$$

Now, if $\operatorname{Re} a>0$ then $|\frac{2a-1}{2a+1}|<1$.  Important fact: $\sup_{x\ge 0} |L_n(x)| e^{-x/2} = L_n(0) = 1$ for all $n$. ( reference [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/18.14#E8)  ). We conclude that in the above we have normal convergence in $x$. ( $a$ in a compact subset of the right half plane). In particular  every
$e^{-a x}$ can be approximated uniformly by functions $e^{-x/2} P(x)$.

The functions $L_n(x) e^{-x/2}$ form an orthonormal system in $L^2[0, \infty)$. The Laguerre expansion of every function $e^{-a x}$ converges normally to $e^{-a x}$. We could obtain the expansion of other functions if we knew their inverse [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform).