# Results that seem trivial, but are not

Tags: soft-question

I saw the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem)

> Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a $n\times n$-matrix, and $p(\lambda)=\det(\lambda \mathbf{I}_n-\mathbf{A})$ the characteristic polynomial of $\mathbf{A}$. Then $p(\mathbf{A})=\mathbf{0}$

and I thought it was trivial since $\det(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{A})=0$. I checked with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem#A_bogus_%22proof%22:_p(A)_=_det(AIn_%E2%88%92_A)_=_det(A_%E2%88%92_A)_=_0) and learned that this didn't work because $\lambda$ is a scalar, and $\det(\mathbf{0})$ is also a scalar, and not a matrix. This brings me to my question:

Are there any other results that seem trivial, but aren't?

Comment: Queen Dido's approach to the isoperimetric problem seems relevant.  Richard Tapia wrote ([2013](http://www.caam.rice.edu/~rat/cv/tapia_euler.pdf)), "When first introduced to this problem, even the less mathematically initiated individuals readily conjecture that the solution is the circle."  However the history of attempts at a fully rigorous proof cover two thousand years.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["It looks straightforward, but actually it isn't"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415365/it-looks-straightforward-but-actually-it-isnt), or [What seemingly innocuous results in mathematics require advanced proofs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2394388/what-seemingly-innocuous-results-in-mathematics-require-advanced-proofs)

Answer (score 3):

The [Jordan curve theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem) states that, if you draw a closed non-intersecting curve in the plane, it divides the plane into those points that are inside the curve, outside it or on it.

Answer (score 2):

The weak Goldbach conjecture (a theorem now, it seems, proved by Harald Helfgott): Every odd integer $n>5$ is a sum of three primes. If you try yourself examples, this seems trivially true. There are millions of possibilities for a big odd $n$. Nevertheless, the proof is extremely complicated.

Comment: In case anyone doesn't know, it was proved in 2013 by Harald Helfgott. (I looked it up because I didn't realise it had even been proven.)

Comment: Yes, there are $5$ arXiv papers, see wikipedia. However, an article with a proof has not been published in a journal yet.